# Two stochastically continuous processes with the same finite dimensional distribution on a dense setvhave the same fdd everywhere?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Two stochastically continuous  processes on $[0,T]$ with the same finite dimensional distribution on a dense subset of $[0,T]$ have the same finite dimensional everywhere?
The processes live on different spaces.

I suspect that this is true since Skorokhod seems to be using this in his book "Studies in the Theory of Random Processes" which I am self studying . Can somebody point me to some references where I could find a proof or give me a hint.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ and $Y$ are processes agreeing on a dense set $S$, then

$$ \mathbf{P}(X_t < A) = \mathbf{P}( \limsup_{s < t} X_s < A) = \limsup_{s < t} \mathbf{P}(X_s < A) = \limsup_{s< t} \mathbf{P}(Y_s < A) = \mathbf{P}(Y_t < A) $$

The biggest jump in the calculation is moving the limsip out of the probability, but this follows by continuity, because $X_t$ is less than $A$ only when the $X_s$ to the left are eventually less than $A$. This idea can easily be generalized to finite sequences of random variables, so all f.d.d. agree.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the first  and the second equality? How would  this reasoning  work if $X_t$ takes values in an arbitrary borel set?

Comment: Does it also work if Y is not necessarily stochastic continuous?

Comment: @user3503589 This distribution of a random variable is uniquely determine by it's cumulative distribution function, i.e. the values $\mathbf{P}(X_t < A)$, or the values $\mathbf{P}(X_t \leq A)$, and so on and so forth (you can see this from $\pi$ $\lambda$ theory, if you're interested.

Comment: @user3503589 No, then the last equality fails, where we move the limsup back into the calculation. Both processes need to be continuous.

Comment: In my particular case only one process is stochastically continuous from the right, the other is defined only on the a dense subset of $[t_0,T]$ i.e it not a continuum of random variables but r.vs only only dense subset

Comment: But you said they were both continuous?

Comment: I am sorry Jacob , I didnt think that the solution presented would use the stochastic continuity of both the processes. I know that one process is stochastic continuous and i get the second process as a result of the Skorokhod construction of rvs  only in the dense subset of $[t_0,T]$. I need to somehow show that i can extend  the newly constructed  discrete process on the dense subset of $[t_0,T]$ to every where on $[t_0,T]$ such that the two processes have the same finite dimensional distribution. Do you get what I am saying?